# Vaadin login actions

Tags: vaadin

I need to perform some actions after user credentials validation both in case of success and failure.
In case of success, I may need to log the user information in the database, validate if the password has expired and if expired allow the user to login but force the user to change the password. And if the user is logged in from a new browser, need to send a OTP and redirect the user to the OTP screen. Or if the user is logged in from else where need to ask the user if he intends to force logout that session.
In case of failure, I need to lock the user and send a email alert.
So in all these cases, I need to perform activities on successful login and failure. How do we do it using Spring security and Vaadin?